# JS Fiddle: Making div occupy 100% height

Tags: jquery, html, css, jsfiddle

I was preparing a fiddle to ask another question but stumbled into an other issue when making fiddle of that.

Here's the link to [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/krish7878/a2tkorno/).

HTML Code:

```
<div class="outer-container">
            <div class="inner-container">
                <div class="slider-one slide" style="background-image:url('http://208.131.135.54/~imacre17/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/homeslide1a.png'); height: 100%; background-size: cover;" class="slider-background-image' ">
                    <div class="slide-inner-container">

                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div><!-- /.slide-inner-container -->
                </div><!-- /.slide -->
                <div class="slider-one slide" style="background-image:url('http://208.131.135.54/~imacre17/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/2-Home-membership.jpg'); height: 100%; background-size: cover;" class="slider-background-image' ">
                    <div class="slide-inner-container">
                        <!-- More content here soon -->
                    </div><!-- /.slide-inner-container -->
                </div><!-- /.slide -->
                <div class="slider-one slide" style="background-image:url('http://208.131.135.54/~imacre17/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/2-Home-special-events.jpg'); height: 100%; background-size: cover;" class="slider-background-image' ">
                    <div class="slide-inner-container">
                        <!-- More content here soon -->
                    </div><!-- /.slide-inner-container -->
                </div><!-- /.slide -->
                <div class="slider-one slide" style="background-image:url('http://208.131.135.54/~imacre17/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/CORKHome-_position4.jpg'); height: 100%; background-size: cover;" class="slider-background-image' ">
                    <div class="slide-inner-container">
                        <!-- More content here soon -->
                    </div><!-- /.slide-inner-container -->
                </div><!-- /.slide -->


            </div><!-- /.inner-container -->
        </div><!-- /.outer-container -->
```

There are four div with class of .slide, each one of them has a background image added to it as inline-style. Each div also has 100% height applied to it.

If I apply the same styles in a HTML page all is well, here's the [link](http://isotopethemes.com/slider-test/new-slider.html). How do I make the div occupy 100% height.

Comment: so whats your problem it is not responsive? please explain whats happening and what you need to solve in this? @chandan

Comment: And your question is??

Comment: @AndrewLyndem: It's in the title, making div stretch 100% height. Thank you for the down vote.

Comment: @Chandan I did not downvote this. I just asked what the question is.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `position:fixed; height:100%;` to slide class

Comment: @Gary: Thank you for the answer, but that was not the issue, my jquery code was wrong.

Comment: @chandan That was Abdollah's answer, I just edited the formatting

Comment: @Gary: Sorry, weird stuff happening for this question, somebody gave me the answer that my jquery was wrong, but moments later they deleted it.

Answer (score 1):

My jquery code was wrong:

this code:

```
var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
var viewportHeight = $(window).height();

$("*").css({"width": viewportWidth, "height": viewportHeight});
```

Solved the issue.